# Is there a way to approve an app just for demonstration

Tags: facebook

I'm going to have a demonstration for high school students. I need to have an app to show them how cool technology is and how simple it's to develop Facebook app.
Therefore I don't have any privacy policy and I'm just looking for a quick app to build for it.

Would it be possible to approve one for that specific use?
This is my app url:
https://developers.facebook.com/apps/658887610853081/settings/

Thanks

Comment: If you just going to demo it then you don't have to take the app live and you don't need a privacy policy. If you are going to take your app live you will need one

Answer (score 0):

No. You can not publish it without getting it approved. You can add testers though.